# Should we add an "entity-framework-core-7" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

There's a new (November 2022) release of EF Core — version 7, which has some major differences from previous versions (e.g. it doesn't support lazy loading, as for now).

Should there be a specific tag for it? I suggest *[entity-framework-core-7]*? I'm not yet allowed to create new tags.

**EDIT**: yes, *[ef-core-7.0]* exists, I didn't find it because I expected it to be similar to the previous tags (e.g. *[entity-framework-core-3.1]*). I now suggest renaming it to *[entity-framework-core-7]* so that it's easy to find (this discrepancy leads to misunderstandings like my question).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/entity-framework-core/info

> Please add a version-specific [ef-core-x] tag, when applicable.

There is [ef-core-7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ef-core-7.0).

Also:

> it doesn't support lazy loading, as for now

[It does though](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy), and that's not a change from 6 to 7?

You can instead turn this into a synonym request to remove the extraneous tags:

- [entity-framework-core-2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core-2.1) to [ef-core-2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ef-core-2.1)
- [entity-framework-core-2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core-2.2) to [ef-core-2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ef-core-2.2)
- [entity-framework-core-3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core-3.0) to [ef-core-3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ef-core-3.0)
- [entity-framework-core-3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core-3.1) to [ef-core-3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ef-core-3.1)

Comment: Thanks, I was misled by this discrepancy. I didn't know about [ef-core-7.0].

Comment: **Entity Framework Core 7 does not support lazy loading.** Look at the last modification date of the article you linked — 2021 year! EF Core 7 released in 2022! [Here](https://www.perplexity.ai/search/a0a6eac2-2ecc-44f1-a1ce-cc2970f9c03f?s=mn) are some sources wrapped up by AI.

Comment: @SNBS ... did you read the text that you link to? It says and I quote: *"Entity Framework Core does not support lazy loading out of the box, but it can be enabled explicitly using one of the following ways"*. That to me reads like... it does support it.

Comment: @Gimby Previous versions supported lazy loading *out of the box*, and I'm talking about the differences.